# Finding the critical points using ln equations

Tags: calculus

I have found the derivative which is $f'(x)=\ln(3x-9)+\frac{x-4}{3x-9}$ and I know I set that $f'(x)=0$ but how do I solve for $\ln$ when it equals $0$?

Comment: What was your original function?  Are you forgetting a chain rule?  The derivative of $\ln(3x-9)$ is $\frac{1}{x-3}$.

Comment: @user113654: As currently written , you would need the http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html. Are you sure you found the derivative correctly?

Comment: Please, provide the original function.

Answer (score 0):

If your equation is:
$$
ln \left( 3x-9 + \frac{x-4}{3x-9} \right) = 0
$$
then $x = 1/9 (28 - \sqrt{10}) $ or $x = 1/9 (28 + \sqrt{10}) $

if your equation is (what I think is):
$$
ln ( 3x-9 ) + \frac{x-4}{3x-9} = 0
$$
you have to use a Lambert's function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).